# How can I remove DRM from my Kindle books?

Tags: kindle, drm

How can I remove DRM from Kindle books I've purchased from Amazon?

Comment: While I agree completely with the points in your moral aside, do be aware that circumventing DRM - even for fully legitimate, Fair Use purposes - is illegal in the US under the Digital Millennium Copyright Act.

Comment: @DaveSherohman: I disagree, but this isn't the place to discuss it. Please see the meta thread I posted when this question was closed: [Is discussion of techniques for removing DRM permitted?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2212/is-discussion-of-techniques-for-removing-drm-permitted).

Comment: @user - I assume the bounty you opened for the question not having enough attention was to get another answer and not reward and existing answer. It's too bad you cannot award that bounty 100% to someone that may be able to help since you are suspended for such a long period of time. I don't think you can even reply back on a comment either. Suspended for over a year too.

Comment: Assuming @PimpJuice is correct, it would be helpful to know what's wrong with the existing accepted answer.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is [a set of Python scripts for removing DRM from several different eBook formats](https://apprenticealf.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/drm-removal-tools-for-ebooks/), including Kindle's.  One of them (called KindleBooks) allows you to remove the DRM without needing Kindle for PC.  Instead it just uses the serial number from the Kindle they were purchased for to decode the books.  It worked great for books downloaded on my Kindle 2.

It also has handy plugins for [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/), which is open source software for reading and converting various eBook formats as well as syncing to many different kinds of eBook readers.  I highly recommend it.

The above tools work great on Linux, and should work fine on Mac OS X too as they are all Python-based.  In order to run them, you will need to install Python for [Windows](http://www.python.org/download/windows/) or [Mac](http://www.python.org/download/mac/) (which comes with Python, but apparently has older versions), or make sure you have packages for Python and its Tk binding installed on your Linux system.

Comment: Worked perfectly on my Mac (I have previously installed Python 2.7 for development, I don't know if it works with the default version). Thank you.

Comment: Python for mac from MacPorts is better.

Comment: The Calibre + plugin worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

Recently, I de-drm'd our family's collection of purchased Kindle e-books using [skindle](http://roke-isle.blogspot.com/2010/05/unskindle-step-by-step-guide.html).  The link is to a blog post giving step-by-step instructions for using it.  It's Windows only and relies on having an installed version of [Kindle for PC](http://www.amazon.com/gp/kindle/pc).

Here is an abbreviated summary of the instructions:

- Download and extract the skindle package
- Download, install, and register Kindle for PC
- Use Kindle for PC to download a local copy of a book from your library
- Run skindle against the file with the appropriate arguments
- Backup the resulting file however you want.  If you need to put it back on your kindle in the future, just drop it into the Documents folder on the device.

Answer (score 11):

The article [Ebook Formats, DRM and You — A Guide for the Perplexed](http://apprenticealf.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/ebooks-formats-drm-and-you-%E2%80%94-a-guide-for-the-perplexed/), describes how to remove DRM from Kindle books, using several methods :

1. The simplest way is to use [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/), as described in the article.
2. Mac OS X 10.5, 10.6, and 10.7 users who don’t want to use calibre should use the DeDRM AppleScript, as described in the post, [DeDRM AppleScript for Mac OS X 10.5, 10.6, and 10.7](http://apprenticealf.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/dedrm-applescript-for-mac-os-x-10-5-10-6/).
3. Windows users who don’t want to use calibre will need to install Python and PyCrypto and use either the DeDRM_WinApp tool or the stand-alone tools, as described in the post, [Windows, Python, Ebooks and DRM](http://apprenticealf.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/windows-python-ebooks-and-drm/).
4. Linux users may also use the Windows versions of the tools under the very latest 1.3.22 or later versions of Wine.

If you encounter problems, see also the
[Frequently Asked Questions about the DRM removal tools](http://apprenticealf.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/frequently-asked-questions-about-the-drm-removal-tools/).

Answer (score 2):

Since undoing DRM for personal use seems now
[acceptable](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2212/is-discussion-of-techniques-for-removing-drm-permitted),
here is a procedure that has worked for me.

**Install an older version of Kindle for PC**

The new version has changed the format of its downloaded books,
so an older version is required, for example
[Kindle for PC 1.17.0 Build 44170](https://filehippo.com/download_kindle_for_pc/69970/).

As on installation it will immediately update itself to the latest version,
it is recommended to install it while Internet is turned off, and disable
auto-update in the Options before connecting to your account.

After turning on the Internet and connecting to your account, download your
books to the computer. They will by default be found in the folder
`C:\Users\USER\Documents\My Kindle Content` and have strange names.

The latest file with the extension of `.azw` is the downloaded book.

**Install Calibre**

Download and install the free
[Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/)
library with its excellent e-book reader for many formats.

**Install tools**

In
[Apprentice Alf’s Blog](https://apprenticealf.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/drm-removal-tools-for-ebooks/)
is a discussion of the tools which can be downloaded from the releases page
[DRM Removal Tools for eBooks](https://github.com/apprenticeharper/DeDRM_tools/releases).

Unzip the tools, find the Calibre plug-in and install it in Calibre
(instructions included with the files).

**Add books to the Calibre library**

Adding the `.azw` book to Calibre will automatically invoke the
DeDRM tools to undo the DRM, and the book will be added to your Calibre library,
where you may read it with the supplied viewer, or convert it to another format.